# File upload checking REAL file mime type when uploading directly to S3

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3, dropzone.js

I'm using DropzoneJS to upload files **directly to S3**. When they add I file I am using my backend to check the mime type and create the S3 signature. When I say adding I file, I just means it's added it to the Dropzone queue so the file isn't uploaded yet it's just sending metadata about the file to the `/upload/sign` url.

```
this.on('addedfile', function (file) {
                    $.get('/upload/sign', {
                        name: file.name,
                        size: file.size,
                        type: file.type,
                    }).done(function (response) {
                        myDropzone.options.url = response.attributes.action;
                        file.additionalData = response.additionalData;
                        myDropzone.processFile(file);
                    }).fail(function (response) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);

                        myDropzone.emit('error', file, data);
                    });
                });
```

This is all good! The problem is the file's mime type is only determined by the file extension, so I can happily rename a file from `image.jpg` to `image.mp3` and `file.type` will be `audio/mp3`. This I guess is fine for browser warnings, but not if I want that mp3 to play or if I eventually want to process the audio!

Is there any way of telling the REAL mime type of the file, without having to pass the upload directly to the servers file system? I need to upload directly to S3 so passing it through an EC2 is not an option.

Comment: You mean directly uploading the file using aws s3 console?

Comment: @notionquest No using DropzoneJS javascript library

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope, not yet unfortunately